# Laplace of sum of shifted diracs : $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-nT)$

Tags: analysis, laplace-transform, signal-processing, dirac-delta

I want to compute : $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-nT)$$
I tried as such:
$$\cal{L} \Big( \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-nT)  \Big)=  \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\cal{L}(\delta(t-nT)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-snT} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{0}e^{-snT} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-snT}$$

The second one converges (geometric series) but the first one?

Comment: Remember that the support of the Laplace transform integral is the non-negative real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake after the second equality; indeed, one has
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\mathscr{L}[\delta(t-nT)](s) = \sum_{n=\color{red}{0}}^\infty e^{-snT}
$$
since
$$
\mathscr{L}[\delta(t-nT)](s) = \int_{0^-}^\infty\delta(t-nT)e^{-st}\,\mathrm{d}t = 
\begin{cases}
   e^{-snT} & \mathrm{if}\quad n\ge0 \\
   0        & \mathrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Laplace transform is usually defined on the positive half-axis. Do you want to use two-sided Laplace transform? It has rather strict convergence requirements.

I would suggest to use Fourier transform (of distributions) instead, which [yields another Dirac comb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb#Fourier_transform) after some regularization.